# Update a DataGridView for different users logged in

Tags: c#

I have a C# student management app and I want to update the DataGridView for each user. For example, a teacher can`t have all the students from a high school and he don't want to see other teachers students, so how can I make to display different data in the DataGridView for different users who logged in?

Comment: Create a ViewModel for data binding.
Have a property say DesiredData  (.i.e results specific to a teacher)
Populate the DesiredData in the view model based on the login user.
Bind the DesiredData to the data source property.

Comment: We could suggest something relevant if you could provide working code snippets.

Comment: Here is a function to display students in a DataGridView: `        public DataTable getStudentlist(SqlCommand command)
        {
            command.Connection = connect.getconnection;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }`

Comment: @Genam Omer here we can have two scenarios
For Case 1 : We are ok query students on Teacher change:
We can modify the SQL query to select only the desired students with teacher in where filter.
For Case 2 : We are not ok query students on every teacher change.
We can query all the students once and store them in an in-memory collection. There after when teacher changes. We can reassign the DataGrid view binding collection with the relevant results by using LINQ filters on in-memory collection.